# Move data from one input field to another

Tags: jquery

I have an admin form I'm creating that has four different areas with similar fields (Title, Description, Image & URL). I want to be able to move data from one Area to another and carry all of that data from field to field. So, clicking on a move down link will move all the information in the first area (Title, Description, Image & URL) into the 2nd area.

So, how do I move the value of one text field to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#move_down_link').click(function() {
    $('input_1').val($('input_2').val())
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.val()` to get the value of a text field. and also use `.val('text')` to set the text.

So you would get the value of your first one, save it in a variable and then set the next one with that.

```
title = $('form.class .title').val();

$('form2.class .title').val(title);
```

Obviously I'm just guessing your jQuery selectors there.